# Search angular JS with price slider noUiSlider

Tags: angularjs, slider, nouislider

I started in AngularJS, I have a product list with a type and price

```
$scope.produits = [{"ID":77,"title":"frite","prix":"5","type":"aliment"},{"ID":88,"title":"marteau","prix":"7","type":"outil"},{"ID":88,"title":"masse","prix":"10","type":"outil"}];
```

I managed to do a search with input text to filter results on title, price and type. then, i set a nouislider and i would like that shows only the products between a min and max price while keeping the ability to search with my inputs.

Is anybody can help me on that.

Thank you :)

(You can find my code and test it)

```js
<!-- slider -->
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
 start: [5, 20],
 step: 1,
 connect: true,
 range: {
  'min': 5,
  'max': 20
 }
});

var skipValues = [
 document.getElementById('skip-value-lower'),
 document.getElementById('skip-value-upper')
];

slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
 skipValues[handle].value = values[handle];
});
<!-- fin slider -->

<!-- code angular -->
var app = angular.module('tutoApp', ['produitModule']);

var produitModule = angular.module('produitModule', []);
produitModule.controller('produitController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
}]);

produitModule.controller("produitController", function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.produits = [{"ID":77,"title":"frite","prix":"5","type":"aliment"},{"ID":88,"title":"marteau","prix":"7","type":"outil"},{"ID":88,"title":"masse","prix":"10","type":"outil"}];
});
<!-- fin code angular -->
```

```html
<html ng-app="tutoApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.3.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>


<link rel='stylesheet' id='nouislider-css-css'  href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.3.0/nouislider.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />


<div ng-controller="produitController">
  title <input type="text" ng-model="search.title"><br>
  type <input type="text" ng-model="search.type"><br>
  prix <input type="text" ng-model="search.prix">

  <div id="slider" style="width: 200px;margin:20px;"></div>

  <input id="skip-value-lower" type="text" value="5">
  <input id="skip-value-upper" type="text" value="20" >


  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="produit in filtered  = (produits | filter:search)">- 
   l'id {{produit.ID}}<br>
   le titre {{produit.title}}<br>
   type {{produit.type}}<br>
   prix {{produit.prix}}<br>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: StackOverflow expects questions to be asked in English

Comment: Update the question itself with translation and any new relevant information

Comment: ok, thanks (I am a beginner with stackoverflow too :) )